# ClearAll works on all variables except "h"?

Tags: core-language

I have a seemingly very strange problem.

I have first defined a function $h$ as follows:

```
h[x_]:=x^2
```

And I also defined some other variables.

Then however, I wanted to clear these variables, but it seems that it doesn't clear $h$, for no apparent reason. I even added Remove to be sure:

> [image]

(It doesn't say anything about $j$)

**What's going on here?**

Comment: `h` won't be cleared because it has the `Protected` attribute. For me, `ClearAll` gives a message saying this.

Comment: `Unprotect[h]; ClearAll[h]`

Comment: @C.E. It doesn't give me that message, but thanks!

Comment: @corey979, thanks it works!